# I am only getting a single repository back

Tags: github-api

I just started learning how to use the GitHub API. I wrote a sample program, to list my repositories. I have 5 repos, and I am only getting one. Any ideas?

My code:

```
<? php

DEFINE ('PERSONAL_TOKEN', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$headers = [
    'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json',
    'User-Agent: Some Text',
    'Authorization: token '. PERSONAL_TOKEN
];

$res = list_repositories($headers);

print "<pre>";
print_r($res);
print "</pre>";

function list_repositories($headers)
{
    $curl_url = GITHUB_REST_URL.'myusernameful'.'/repos';
    $ch = curl_init($curl_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $res = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), TRUE);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
```

I was expecting to get all 5 of my repos, instead, I am only getting one back:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 168594503
            [node_id] => MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkxNjg1OTQ1MDM=
            [name] => repo_one
            [full_name] => myusername/repo_one
            [private] => 
            [owner] => Array
                (
                    [login] => myusername
                    [id] => 45577729
                    [node_id] => MDQ6VXNlcjQ1NTc3NzI5
                    [avatar_url] => https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/45577729?v=4
                    [gravatar_id] => 
                    [url] => https://api.github.com/users/myusername
                    [html_url] => https://github.com/myusername
                    [followers_url] => https://api.github.com/users/myusername/followers
                    [following_url] => https://api.github.com/users/myusername/following{/other_user}
                    [gists_url] => https://api.github.com/users/myusername/gists{/gist_id}
                    [starred_url] => https://api.github.com/users/myusername/starred{/owner}{/repo}
                    [subscriptions_url] => https://api.github.com/users/myusername/subscriptions
                    [organizations_url] => https://api.github.com/users/myusername/orgs
                    [repos_url] => https://api.github.com/users/myusername/repos
                    [events_url] => https://api.github.com/users/myusername/events{/privacy}
                    [received_events_url] => https://api.github.com/users/myusername/received_events
                    [type] => User
                    [site_admin] => 
                )

            [html_url] => https://github.com/myusername/repo_one
            [description] => repo_one makes it easy and fast to build beautiful mobile apps.
            [fork] => 1
            [url] => https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/repo_one
            [forks_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/repo_one/forks
            [keys_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/repo_one/keys{/key_id}
            [collaborators_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/repo_one/collaborators{/collaborator}
            [teams_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/repo_one/teams
            [hooks_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/repo_one/hooks
            [issue_events_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/repo_one/issues/events{/number}
            [events_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/repo_one/events
            [assignees_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/repo_one/assignees{/user}
            [branches_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/repo_one/branches{/branch}
            [tags_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/repo_one/tags
            [blobs_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/repo_one/git/blobs{/sha}
            [git_tags_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/repo_one/git/tags{/sha}
            [git_refs_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/repo_one/git/refs{/sha}
            [trees_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/repo_one/git/trees{/sha}
            [statuses_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/repo_one/statuses/{sha}
            [languages_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/repo_one/languages
            [stargazers_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/repo_one/stargazers
            [contributors_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/repo_one/contributors
            [subscribers_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/repo_one/subscribers
            [subscription_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/repo_one/subscription
            [commits_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/repo_one/commits{/sha}
            [git_commits_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/repo_one/git/commits{/sha}
            [comments_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/repo_one/comments{/number}
            [issue_comment_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/repo_one/issues/comments{/number}
            [contents_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/repo_one/contents/{+path}
            [compare_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/repo_one/compare/{base}...{head}
            [merges_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/repo_one/merges
            [archive_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/repo_one/{archive_format}{/ref}
            [downloads_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/repo_one/downloads
            [issues_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/repo_one/issues{/number}
            [pulls_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/repo_one/pulls{/number}
            [milestones_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/repo_one/milestones{/number}
            [notifications_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/repo_one/notifications{?since,all,participating}
            [labels_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/repo_one/labels{/name}
            [releases_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/repo_one/releases{/id}
            [deployments_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/repo_one/deployments
            [created_at] => 2019-01-31T20:50:56Z
            [updated_at] => 2019-02-01T22:17:23Z
            [pushed_at] => 2019-01-31T20:48:11Z
            [git_url] => git://github.com/myusername/repo_one.git
            [ssh_url] => git@github.com:myusername/repo_one.git
            [clone_url] => https://github.com/myusername/repo_one.git
            [svn_url] => https://github.com/myusername/repo_one
            [homepage] => https://repo_one.io
            [size] => 52581
            [stargazers_count] => 0
            [watchers_count] => 0
            [language] => Dart
            [has_issues] => 
            [has_projects] => 1
            [has_downloads] => 1
            [has_wiki] => 1
            [has_pages] => 
            [forks_count] => 0
            [mirror_url] => 
            [archived] => 
            [open_issues_count] => 0
            [license] => Array
                (
                    [key] => other
                    [name] => Other
                    [spdx_id] => NOASSERTION
                    [url] => 
                    [node_id] => MDc6TGljZW5zZTA=
                )

            [forks] => 0
            [open_issues] => 0
            [watchers] => 0
            [default_branch] => master
            [permissions] => Array
                (
                    [admin] => 1
                    [push] => 1
                    [pull] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "[List your Repositories](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-your-repositories)" is `/user/repos`, not `/users/:username/repos`.

If you use your GitHub username in the URL (as in the latter case), you would get only your *public* repositories, not *all* your repos (public and private)

Comment: OK, how do I get all the repos? or for that matter, how do I specify public or private?

Comment: @EastsideDeveloper /user/repos gets all your repos. And you can add to your query ?visibility=...: string (Can be one of all, public, or private. Default: all), for filtering the result. Said result includes a field `"private": false/true` for each repos.

Comment: Thanks. I was getting confused between user and users. It worked